# Share new directory via git repository

Tags: git

I am using git to share a project across several computers. On one machine, I create a new directory (with various files in it) within the project. I then pushed this to the repository with the following:

```
git add directoryname
git commit -m "Adding a new directory"
```

Judging by the list of files, it seemed to commit everything. However, if I then issue the command

```
git pull
```

on another machine, the new directory doesn't appear. I've tried various other options e.g. `git fetch` but each time it says the local repository is already up-to-date. How can I pull this new directory down from the repository?

Comment: How are the other repositories configured? What is the output of `git remote -v` in the different repositories

Answer (score 3):

You need to push it from the computer where you commited

```
git push origin mybranch
```

You can add the `-u` flag if you want to track it, so the next time you use `git push` it will push automatically the branch there.

Comment: I suggest adding `-u` flag (`git push -u origin mybranch`), so that next time you can simply write `git push`. Also, if you don't know what branch is, just use `master` (`git push -u origin master`).

Comment: Judging by the length of time git push took, I think this was uploading the folder and data (some quite large files). I used `git push -u origin master` however git pull still doesn't bring this new directory into the local repository on my other machine.

Comment: [Update] I ran through the following sequence: `git commit -am "New changes" , git push origin master` followed by `git pull` on the other machine. The new directory, one of the subdirectories, and one of the files therein have now appeared on my other computer. I've no idea why git isn't transferring everything or why it chose certain files.

Answer (score 0):

Where do you host your repositories? There are many different options for this. This example uses `GitHub`

First, you must register with `GitHub`

> https://github.com/

After you've done it, make sure you remember your login details.

Create a repository by clicking

[image: button]

Give it a name

[image: gelloworld]

Do your work on the project

```
git add .
git commit -m "Behold my awesome feature"
```

Grab a link to your remote repository

[image: repos]

Set up your remote repository on your machine

```
git remote add project01 https://github.com/edoroskevic/helloworld.git
```

***Note:*** `project01` can be replaced with whatever you like. It's simply a name for your remote repository that will be stored on your local machine.

After it has been set-up you can finally push your work to remote repository

```
git push project01 master
```

***Note*:** `project01` is the name I have given to this test repository and `master` is the branch I will be pushing to my remote repository.

After executing the above command you will be asked to provide your login details to `GitHub` (username, password). Enter those and check out your pushed updates on `GitHub`.

You may get a nasty `fatal error` when pushing. Saying something like...

> Can't merge unrelated histories...

In that case you can run your push with `-f` like so

```
git push -f origin master
```

Note: `-f` will force the push on top of your remote. You can also add links between local and remote branches but this post is getting a bit too long.

Next time you are on another machine, you can

```
git clone https://github.com/edoroskevic/helloworld.git
```

This will clone the remote repository and set up all the links between branches automatically. Next you just keep doing your usual stuff adding, committing and pushing

Hope its helpful :s

Comment: Note: private repos on Github aren't free.

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus that's true

Answer (score -1):

The sequence that eventually worked is as follows:

Host 1 (containing new directory, 'Dir_new', with various subdirectories and files)

```
git add directoryname
git commit -m "Adding a new directory"
git push origin master
```

Host 2

```
git fetch
git checkout HEAD
git pull
```

Note this only transfers subdirectories which contain files. Any empty subdirectories are ignored.